# How to make a QML Canvas visible?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qml

I'm trying to draw something on the screen in an Ubuntu phone application.
I created a new "QML App with Simple UI (qmlproject)" in Ubuntu SDK, and replaced the content of `Main.qml` with the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1

MainView {
    objectName: "mainView"

    applicationName: "canvasexample.cos64"

    useDeprecatedToolbar: false

    width: units.gu(50)
    height: units.gu(50)

    Page {
        title: i18n.tr("Canvas Example")

        Canvas {
            anchors {
                margins: units.gu(2)
                fill: parent
            }
            id: canvas
            width: 100
            height: 200
            onPaint: {
                console.log("on paint");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                ctx.save();
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.lineTo(75,70);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.restore();
            }

            onPainted: {
                console.log("painted");
            }

            MouseArea {
                id: buttonMouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("clicked");
                    canvas.requestPaint();
                }
            }

            Component.onCompleted: {
                console.log("completed")
            }

            onScaleChanged: {
                console.log("scale changed")
            }

            onRotationChanged: {
                console.log("rotated");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get no errors, but the canvas is not visible, although I can click on it, as the console output shows:

```
Starting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmlscene...
qml: completed
qml: on paint
qml: painted
qml: clicked
qml: on paint
qml: painted
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmlscene exited with code 0
```

Here's what the running app looks like:

[image: Screenshot of Canvas Example]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ctx.save();
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(75,90);
ctx.lineTo(75,70);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

**edit**

If someone is looking for an academic explanation, the problem is that you need two points to draw a line and apparently the library doesn't supply you with a starting point. You should set it with the `moveTo` method. Setting starting point with `lineTo` happens to work, but it is not clearly documented as such (so it may and will break).

Comment: You are right, Velkan, this way it works. Looks like I wasn't using the drawing API correctly.